# Is it safe to par-boil chicken legs, (unthawed), then finish cooking them later?

Tags: food-safety, boiling

I boiled four chicken legs for 25 mins, put them in the fridge then took them back out to finish boiling them four hours later, is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, as long as the chicken doesn't stay more than 2 hours in the [danger zone](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/shared/PDF/Danger_Zone.pdf?redirecthttp=true) (40-140* F / 4-60º C). These 2 hours include preparation, cooking time and storage.

For further information: [Is a partially frozen chicken safe if not immediately cooked at the proper temperature?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32473/23376) and [Can chicken not completely cooked then cooled be fully cooked later?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4428/23376)