# Re-roast an undercooked chicken?

Tags: food-safety

My roasted chicken bled while it rested under foil. I refrigerated it over night. Can I bake it more today to finish it without drying it out?

Comment: I agree with the duplicate -- particularly this answer though https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4469/17272