# Hours for bacteria to form on raw steak

Tags: steak, raw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it dangerous to eat meat which has been left out and then cooked?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked)

I left raw  steak on the cement floor for 18 hrs.  Should I not eat it because the meat has gone bad?  If not, is there a way of saving it?  I froze it immediately.  Does freezing stop the bacteria from growing?

Answer (score 3):

This steak should be discarded immediately,

See:  [Why is it dangerous to eat meat which has been left out and then cooked?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked)

While freezing will halt the growth, the pathogens have already had more than enough time to create poisons, some of which are not destroyed by freezing or cooking.

Also, it probably will now taste quite off, but that is not a safety issue.