# Should I roast a rolled beef roast from room temperature?

Tags: beef, roast

It is better to roast a rolled beef roast from room temperature? Or is it advisable to roast it straight from the fridge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't make a huge difference, and excellent chefs disagree on the subject (assuming you're only thinking of leaving the meat out for an hour or so, which actually wouldn't bring it to room temp, just slightly warmer than fridge temp). If you are serving people who prefer different levels of doneness, you can take the cold roast from the fridge and put it into a very hot oven, then immediately turn the oven temperature down to the temp you want for roasting. That will give the greatest variance in doneness of individual servings. A slightly warmer roast to start and a consistent roasting temperature (particularly a temperature on the low side) will more evenly cook the roast.

Don't forget to rest the meat before slicing! And don't forget, how much will depend upon the size of the roast, but its temperature will rise upon resting.

Comment: Any issues with leaving the meat out for 2-3 hours?

Comment: @Petah Yes, you shouldn't. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked. 4 hour *cumulative* in the "danger zone" is the max. Consider prep time, transportation time from the store, everything. If you're even *thinking* about leftovers, then forget it. 1 hour on the counter before cooking...even 2 hours is pushing it. I admit that is extremely conservative, there is room to assess your own risk, but there is risk.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a lot of time for heat to make its way through a roast. If you heat using a high temp, the outside will be browned or crispy...or dried out while the center is still blood red. If the temperature differential is huge, the brown outside, red inside effect is amplified.

I prep the roast by removing the big slabs of fat. I will add generous amounts of salt and pepper or teriyaki sauce. Misu sauce is really good. The roast that's in the oven now is covered with strips of bacon.

If you marinate with pineapple juice, be very careful. Pineapple juice is a great tenderizer but it can also turn the meat into mush.

What I do is cook the beef at low temp. If you cook to say...145...you'll have a nice medium rare roast that's not dried out and not completely raw in the center. The low heat allows the center to cook evenly and predictably. What's more is you end up with nice juicy beef. I have a Hobart slicer so after allowing for some rest time, I slice up my roast and I am in heaven.

It goes without saying, a good thermometer IS AN ABSOLUTE MUST!

If you want a crispy outside, you can broil the roast for a few minutes at the end.

My rule of thumb is 1 hour per pound at 200 degrees. That will get you into the 140F ball park. 140 or medium rare is what I like. The roasts in the store are usually 3 to 4 pounds.

**The answer to the question:** It really doesn't matter. You're cooking until the center gets to the desired doneness. If it comes from the fridge it will take a bit longer.

I just pulled a 3.2 pound roast out of the oven an hour ago. It came straight from the fridge. It was hard to stop snacking on it after slicing.

We're talking about refrigerated roasts, not frozen. In that case, the roast needs to be thawed before proceeding.