# Are the NAAN flatbread {from simply chef} ok to eat without warmed up in the microwave or oven?

Tags: bread

So I was getting something to eat. I didn't think they had to be warmed up. So yea is it safe to do that.the ingredients are enriched wheat flour, wheat flour, niacin, reduced iron,enzyme,ascorbic acid added as a dough conditioner ,thiamine mononitrate,riboflavin,folic acid,water,sugar,baking powder,sodium bicarbonate,cornstarch,monocalcium phosphate,inactive yeast, wheat gluten, calcium propionate (preservative)vitamin D2 Bakers yeast,potassium sorbate,preservative,fumaric acid,lactic acid,calcium lactate. (Contains wheat) may contain soy milk and eggs

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are safe.

The reason why warming up is recommended is simply taste and texture:
When cool, they are more rigid, dry and crumbly, warmed up they become soft and more pleasant to eat. So if you are just hungry, start nibbling.

Regarding the food safety aspects:
**Warming up will in no case make unsafe food safe**, see our [generic post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked) (about meat) why even boiling won't do that. Bread is not a food that is prone to super-fast spoiling and can be safely stored at room temperature. Apart from that, those pre-packaged breads contain preservatives (see your ingredient list) and are typically sealed to prolong shelf life.