# Why worry about "danger zone" when thawing meat if I'm going to be cooking the meat immediately after?

Tags: food-safety, meat, defrosting, thawing

I'm cooking my meat above 55C, mostly around 65C.

I understand there are all kinds of safety measures surrounding defrosting. Using cold water and changing it every 30min or defrosting in the fridge. Making sure not to leave it on the counter or not to use warm/hot water.

This is because of the danger zone; bacteria doubles every ~20 min.

If I am defrosting meat in order to cook it, and I am cooking at safe temperatures, then why should I worry about how I defrost my meat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it dangerous to eat meat which has been left out and then cooked?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked)

Answer (score 1):

> If I am defrosting meat in order to cook it, and I am cooking at safe temperatures, then why should I worry about how I defrost my meat?

If this were true, wouldn't it then follow that it would be safe to cook meat which has already spoiled, so long as you cooked it at a safe temperature?  It's not true.  While the bacteria would be killed by cooking at a safe temperature, but the toxins they leave behind remain and can make you ill.